# Classic ASP site requests randomly hang in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I have a new IIS7 box running Windows Server 2008 Web Edition (x64), and I have set up an existing classic ASP site there.  The site works fine and super speedy for the most part, but will randomly hang (about 1 out of 20 or so requests).  By hanging, I mean I will click a page from the browser, and the browser (Crome on Mac) never responds -- it just continually loads until I finally get the following error after about 3 or so minutes:

```
Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.
```

I'm pretty sure this is a Chrome-specific error, so I'm not too hung up on the actual error, but the cause of the time out.  The site connects to a SQL 2005 server on the same network, but I'm pretty sure this isn't a SQL timeout, as that would happen within 30 seconds, and give me a specific error about SQL.  I think this is an issue w/ my site, or the server.

Note that often after seeing this, I can simply stop the request and reload the page, and it will load just fine, super speedy again.

I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting this.  I have to figure this out, otherwise this will mean a new server purchase down the drain.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: When you say you think it's a Chrome error - have you tried using tools such as Wireshark or Charles to capture the request, and then repeating it by just changing the user-agent string to Firefox or Internet Explorer?

Comment: Also, does this occur on ALL pages, or just some? Have you tried creating a new page which simply prints a statement and testing whether this page is also susceptible to this issue?

Comment: try the site on a 32-bits based machine

Comment: Something similar has been happening on my sites.  Only happens in Chrome on my PC for my websites.  And it's sporadic.  I too am running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008(x64), although I don't know if that has anything to do with it.  I'm a little bit clueless.

Comment: It does seem to be specific to Chrome, now that I've been trying it in Safari for a while.  But it still also seems to be specific to my site on Chrome -- I don't think I've noticed this on other sites, unless it happens and I just don't think about it (I'm obviously more conscious of the performance of my own site).

Comment: @Jerad - I've learned a few things about this problem through experimentation, or rather, moving out of state.  You can see my update below.

Comment: @Steve - That's very interesting. I've actually moved on from this site and am working on a .NET site, so I'm not sure I'll ever figure out what's going on.  It still seems odd though.  Thanks for the update, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a few more things about this problem.  It'll happen more often after I've published files to the server (even static content like js or css files).  It'll also happen occasionally on other sites running ASP.NET.  Namely I've noticed the timeout on dotnetkicks.com which is also running IIS 7.5.  Again, this only occurs in Chrome.

I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing Chrome but the problem continues.  My next step is to try this from a couple different computers running Chrome outside my network.

---

**UPDATE** (April 29, 2011)

So I moved to Colorado a couple weeks ago and I haven't seen this problem occur even once since I moved.  That leads me to conclude that 1.) my internet connection in Dallas was flaky and 2.) Chrome was less forgiving of a poor connection than other browsers.  And of course, it basically rules out any possibility of there being a problem at the server's end.